# PHP - Add variable to switch statement value

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have the following switch statement:

```
$html = '<div class="'. $some_value . '">';

switch ($some_value) {
    case "one":
        return $html . 'One Biscuit</div>';
        break;
    case "two":
        return $html . 'Two Chimps</div>';
        break;
    case "three":
        return $html . 'Three Pies</div>';
        break;
    default:
        return $html . 'Meh...</div>';
}
```

Noticed how I added the `$html` variable to each case? Not good... Is it possible to add it just once to the final value of the switch statement? I'm trying to wrap the final value in the dynamic HTML.

Comment: A more complicated way is using the output buffer, ob_start(),  print out everything then $var = ob_get_clean(); although it may be more complicated than you may need

Comment: And when you use return in the switch statement, you really do not need a break!

Comment: Note: you can put the cases in an array for lookup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this:

```
switch($some_value){
    case 'one':
        $var="One Biscuit";
    break;
    case 'two':
        $var="Two Chimps";
    break;
    case 'three':
        $var="Three Pies";
    break;
    default:
        $var="Meh...";
    break;
}
$html="<div class=".$some_value.">".$var."</div>";
```

Comment: Voted because the HTML is generated at the end end closing the <div> tag once.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it:

```
$html = '<div class="'. $some_value . '">';
$v = 'Meh...</div>';
switch ($some_value) {
    case "one":
        $v = 'One Biscuit</div>';
        break;
    case "two":
        $v = 'Two Chimps</div>';
        break;
    case "three":
        $v = 'Three Pies</div>';
        break;
}

$html .= $v;
```

Since you are using `return`, you can just return once in the end:
`return $html.$v`

Also, you could define a param to the default value, like so:

```
function someFunction(DUNNO_YOUR_PARAMS, $v = 'Meh...'){
    $v .= '</div'>;
    // rest of code
```

Answer (score 2):

Store the string in new variable. Also you do not need a break **after** a return statement.

```
$html = '<div class="'. $some_value . '">';

$str = null;
switch ($some_value) {
    case "one":
        $str = 'One Biscuit</div>';
        break;
    case "two":
        $str = 'Two Chimps</div>';
        break;
    case "three":
        $str = 'Three Pies</div>';
        break;
    default:
        $str = 'Meh...</div>';
        break;
}
return $html.$str;
```

Answer (score 2):

Other ways is saving data in an array:

```
$some_value = 'two';
//
$data = array(//this data could be stored in a database table
  'one'  => 'One Biscuit',
  'two'  => 'Two Chimps',
  'three'=> 'Three Pies',
  'default' => 'Meh...'
);

$html = '<div class="'.$some_value.'">'.(isset($data[$some_value])?$data[$some_value]:$data['default']).'</div>';
var_dump($html);
```

result:

```
string '<div class="two">Two Chimps</div>' (length=33)
```

In some cases array is faster than switch : [In PHP what's faster, big Switch statement, or Array key lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852652/in-php-whats-faster-big-switch-statement-or-array-key-lookup)

Comment: I agree with this answer, however mentioning things like performance for things like this is counter productive and misses the point completely.

Comment: I'm accord with @PeeHaa

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which may be easier to maintain if your html is longer:

```
<?php
ob_start();
echo '<div class="'.$some_var.'">';
/*
Be sure the file exists in the location you want
You can change items to the name of any directory you want just be
sure the file exists in the end. In the case of linux be sure the file
is the exact same name...
*/
include('items/'.$some_var.'.php');
echo '</div>';
$output = ob_get_clean();
return $output;
?>
```

In your files you just put the html code you want.
Example three.php (it really is just the html or plain text unless you process something:

```
Three pies
```

This can probably be refactored if you have too many files that are this simple.  But in the case it is more complex you can include more stuff.