# Switch Case Vs Array Key Lookup, Which is faster considering the space complexity

Tags: php, arrays, switch-statement

I have a switch with 100 cases which I have to go through. So I was wondering that which approach will have less space complexity.

This question

[In PHP what's faster, big Switch statement, or Array key lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852652/in-php-whats-faster-big-switch-statement-or-array-key-lookup?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

somewhat answers the time complexity but they did not take into account the memory factor.

Comment: This is really broad.

Comment: Is there any reason that you cannot reproduce the knowledge from https://stackoverflow.com/q/6852652/2191572 and use [`memory_get_usagee()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) to figure out the rest of whatever you are asking?

Comment: What is the memory factor you are worries about anyways? 100 cases on today's hardware is meh at best.